# Timer in div / event to specific time

Tags: javascript, html, function, timer, dom-events

I have a problem. I am making an addon for Chrome and  I want to check a value each time the timer is at 15 sec in an external website.
I have got this, for example:

```
<div id="timer">17.38</div>
```

or

```
<div id="timer">7.16</div>
```

I need to activate an event when my div is:

```
<div id="timer">15.00</div>
```

I need an event execute function in Javascript.

I need your help please

Answer (score 0):

you can use this :

```
setInterval(function(){

    check_timer();

}
,100)
```

the check function

```
function check_timer(){

   var obj = document.getElementById("timer");

   if (obj.innerHTML == "15.00"){

      //your code here

   }
}
```